# fastlane tools and xcode8, should I still use it?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode8, fastlane

I am using fastlane tools to handle all my signing needs in Xcode 7. As I started using Xcode 8 I've been having some issues. Xcode 8 introduces a new "automatic" signing approach. I am still able to use fastlane tools by telling Xcode not to use automatic signing and by selecting the correct values that come up in the signing options when disabling the automatic check box.

I would like to start using the automatic signing option, but I am not 100% sure how to do it properly using fastlane. I believe I need to understand how to use PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER option?

Can anybody explain how fastlane is supposed to work with Xcode 8 automatic signing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use fastlane for code signing, you should disable automatic code signing and let fastlane do its thing. You can however also enable automatic code signing and let Xcode manage the profiles for you.

You can find more information about how to use fastlane with Xcode 8 and the new Automatic code signing in the [XcodeProject fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/XcodeProject/)

Comment: I wonder if Apple has finally delivered an Xcode that actually handles code signing properly??? We'll see.

Comment: Hey @krausefx, if I choose to let Xcode manage the profiles, what should I change from my current fastfile? Right now it's working, but I'm getting this warning: ```You're using Xcode 7, the `provisioning_profile_path` value will be ignored
[13:00:56]: Please follow the Code Signing Guide: https://codesigning.guide (for match) or https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/CodeSigning.md``` even though I'm using Xcode8 with automatic code signing selected.

Comment: Don't specify the provisioning_profile_path yourself if you do so. Please also share your Fastfile. If you need more help, you can submit an issue on GitHub